# Visual studio 2015 Javascript Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

When I debug my MVC page I am getting Javascript bootstrap error so how can I fix it please help me for resolve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the tab highlighted it has a title of bootstrap.min.js yet the contents are html NOT javascript.

Comment: yes its a script file and visual studio get this automatically when project open. I was getting this error everytime and everywhere at any page.After I click on Continue , I get my Output but I want to remove this error page popup when starting debugging.

Comment: I would look at the content of this file as this is the problem. Maybe it is an error message saying cannot find file or something similar?

Comment: "JavaScript critical error at line 2, column 1 in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error"  - This is first error and "JavaScript critical error at line 2, column 1 in http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error - and this is second error I am getting same time

Comment: Maybe the server hosting the javascript had an error, when I went to the address manually it worked, see here: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: If you replace what is in that file with the content from here it should work: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Thanks andy, the problem was solved by removing two external script bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js, Actually I added both are scripts manually thats why getting error but by removing problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use directly html inside a javascript file

an example on how to use html string with JS.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp

Comment: I am updating my question, I think the problem is in versioning because I will create a mvc page in visual studio 2017 and run using VS 2015 thats why  i am getting script error is it correct or any other problem please suggest me !